Websocket connection in Docker
I have a Node.js app that takes an RTSP URL as input and provide a jsmpeg websocket stream as output. The focus of app is to generate a web compatible stream from an RTSP stream, and  I have acheived this using a package rtsp-relay.
The app is working fine in locally.
But after dockerizing the app, I am not receiving the output stream. The stream is getting terminated.
The log is

The Dockerfile is:
I am building the ffmpeg from source in docker.

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git \
    libass-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libgnutls28-dev \
    libmp3lame-dev \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libtool \
    libva-dev \
    libvdpau-dev \
    libvorbis-dev \
    libxcb1-dev \
    libxcb-shm0-dev \
    libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
    meson \
    ninja-build \
    pkg-config \
    texinfo \
    wget \
    yasm \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libunistring-dev \
    libaom-dev \
    libdav1d-dev \
    libnuma-dev \
    libopus-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create directories
RUN mkdir -p /ffmpeg_sources /ffmpeg_build /bin
RUN apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install -y nasm
RUN  apt-get install -y yasm

# Build and install NASM
WORKDIR /ffmpeg_sources
RUN wget https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.16.01/nasm-2.16.01.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjvf nasm-2.16.01.tar.bz2 && \
    cd nasm-2.16.01 && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="/bin" && \
    make && \
    make install

# Build and install x264
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libx264-dev


# Build and install x265
RUN apt-get install -y libx265-dev libnuma-dev

# Build and install libvpx
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx.git && \
    cd libvpx && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_build" --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --enable-vp9-highbitdepth --as=yasm && \
    make && \
    make install

# Build and install fdk-aac
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac && \
    cd fdk-aac && \
    autoreconf -fiv && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared && \
    make && \
    make install

# Build and install opus
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/xiph/opus.git && \
    cd opus && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix="/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared && \
    make && \
    make install

# Build and install SVT-AV1
RUN git clone --depth=1 https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1.git && \
    cd SVT-AV1 && \
    cd Build && \
    cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release && \
    make && \
    make install


# Build and install dav1d
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dav1d.git && \
    mkdir -p dav1d/build && \
    cd dav1d/build && \
    meson setup -Denable_tools=false -Denable_tests=false --default-library=static .. --prefix "/ffmpeg_build" --libdir="/ffmpeg_build/lib" && \
    ninja && \
    ninja install

# Build and install ffmpeg
RUN wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
    tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 && \
    cd ffmpeg && \
    ./configure \
      --prefix="/ffmpeg_build" \
      --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
      --extra-cflags="-I/ffmpeg_build/include" \
      --extra-ldflags="-L/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
      --ld="g++" \
      --bindir="/bin" \
      --enable-gpl \
      --enable-gnutls \
      --enable-libaom \
      --enable-libass \
      --enable-libfdk-aac \
      --enable-libfreetype \
      --enable-libmp3lame \
      --enable-libopus \
      --enable-libsvtav1 \
      --enable-libdav1d \
      --enable-libvorbis \
      --enable-libvpx \
      --enable-libx264 \
      --enable-libx265 \
      --enable-nonfree \
      --extra-ldflags="-lm -lstdc++ -L/ffmpeg_build/lib -Wl,-rpath,/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
      --extra-cflags="-I/ffmpeg_build/include" \
      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm -lstdc++" && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    hash -r

# Update PATH
ENV PATH="/ffmpeg_build/bin:${PATH}"

# Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /ffmpeg_sources

# Source profile
RUN echo "source /root/.profile" >> ~/.bashrc



WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y npm
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 2000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

While checking the network rules in the Docker image with the command: iptables -L
I am getting the following response:

I am able to access every API of the dockerized app, and I receive the responses and logs. but I'm not receiving the jsmpeg stream through the websocket connection.
I'm uncertain about the exact problem or how to resolve it.If you have encountered a similar issue before, and have a solution, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Check If its use udp Transport for the rtsp Stream or force tcp

@Christoph  Sorry I am new to this. I am using a node libraray link for RTSP conversion. How can I identify it uses UDP or TCP?
